# ResizeMode столбца с нумерацией в QTableWidget PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qss, qtablewidget

Как изменить `ResizeMode` столбца с нумерацией в **`QTableWidget`** и установить `ResizeToContents`? С установкой `ResizeMode` у обычных столбцов проблем нет:

`table.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)`

Но как сделать то же самое со столбцами с автонумерацией? Я пересмотрела все похожие вопросы в интернете, но не нашла ответа. **Зачем это нужно?** Так как по умолчанию почему-то нумерация залазит за грани:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это двузначные числа, а чем они больше, тем больше это наложение, при появлении тысяч последнюю цифру уже почти не видно. Что я пробовала сделать сама:

**1) Я думала, что это будет решением:**

```
table.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```

Но, данный код растягивает все строки по вертикали, в зависимости от контента. Горизонтально строки с нумерацией не растягиваются.

**2) Попытка установить `ResizeToContents` для всех столбцов:**

```
table.resizeSections(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```

Другие столбцы у меня настраиваются отдельно, поэтому на них это не повлияло, но на столбец с нумерацией тоже не повлияло.

**3) Если он расположен перед заголовком с индексом 0, то я подумала, что стоит попробовать следующее:**

```
table.setSectionResizeMode(-1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```

С этим кодом скрылись все заголовки.

Почему происходит это наложение и как его исправить или установить правильные настройки заголовка, чтобы подобного наложения не проиходило?

---

**UPDATE:**

Я разобралась из-за чего числа из нумерации не вмещаются в колонки:

```
setStyleSheet('QWidget { font-size: 16px; font-weight: 500; }')
```

При создании интерфейса в коде, мне не удалось воспроизвести такие же стили, как при использовании Qt Designer. **Создание интерфейса в коде:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('MainWindow')

        self.setStyleSheet('QWidget { font-size: 16px; font-weight: 500; }')

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)

        table = self.tableWidget
        header = table.horizontalHeader()
        header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)

        for tw in range(0, 200):
            row_position = table.rowCount()
            table.insertRow(row_position)

            table.setItem(row_position, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(tw)))
            table.setItem(row_position, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(tw)))

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Его результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код с использованием .ui файла:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('main.ui', self)

        table = self.tableWidget
        header = table.horizontalHeader()
        header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)

        for tw in range(0, 200):
            row_position = table.rowCount()
            table.insertRow(row_position)

            table.setItem(row_position, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(tw)))
            table.setItem(row_position, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(tw)))

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**main.ui:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1079, 600)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QWidget {\n"
"    font-size: 16px;\n"
"    font-weight: 500;\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.tableWidget.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.tableWidget.setAutoScroll(True)
        self.tableWidget.setShowGrid(True)
        self.tableWidget.setGridStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "First"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Second"))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему

Comment: @S.Nick обновила вопрос, добавила примеры кода.

Comment: @Афродита main.ui - 'это должен быть файл формата XML. Если работаете с .ui файлом, то выкладывайте код  и main.py, и XML. Так удобнее разбираться и вам и нам. Если работаете в PyCharm, то правой клавишей мыши кликните на .ui файл и выбирайте Edit with PyCharm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не смотрел ваш первый пример,
в котором вы создаете интерфейс в коде.

Что касается кода с использованием **`.ui`** файла:

- глядя на изображение результата работы, которые вы опубликовали,
  мне показалось, что в таблице используются разные шрифты.
  Добавив немного пикселей

  .....................                vv <------------------------------------------------ 
  "    font-size: 72px;\n" 
  "    font-weight: 500;\n"

Таки да, вот результат (по крайней мере у меня):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Добавляю в таблицу стилей **`font-family`**:

```
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QWidget {\n"
"    font-size: 16px;\n"
"    font-weight: 500;\n"
"    font-family: 'MS Shell Dlg 2';\n"             <---------------   
"}")
```

---

Все, у меня вопрос решен:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит в двух ваших вариантах при одинаковых стилях? 
У меня недостаточно знаний (на данный момент) объяснить тонкости
использования таблиц стилей в Qt
для конкретных виджетов, поэтому я констатирую факт.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(500, 315)
  
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QWidget {\n"
"    font-size: 16px;\n"
"    font-weight: 500;\n"
"    font-family: 'MS Shell Dlg 2';\n"
"}")
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.tableWidget.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.tableWidget.setAutoScroll(True)
        self.tableWidget.setShowGrid(True)
        self.tableWidget.setGridStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidLine)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "First"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Second"))
        

class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
#        uic.loadUi('q1313498.ui', self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        table = self.tableWidget
        header = table.horizontalHeader()
        header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)

        for tw in range(1, 277):
            row_position = table.rowCount()
            table.insertRow(row_position)

            table.setItem(row_position, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(tw)))
            table.setItem(row_position, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(tw)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня нет вашего воспроизводимого примера чтобы проверить, так что просто попробуйте изменить ***verticalHeader()*** на ***horizontalHeader()***:

```
header = self.table.horizontalHeader()       
header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```

или растянуть на всю длину:

```
header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

Comment: я обновила вопрос, добавила примеры кода, эти варианты не помогли